# Make image appear on hover

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position, attr

I'm trying to make a tooltip system, where if the mouse is hovering over a span element with the property `tooltip` (which would would evaluate to the path of an image), the image would display on the top right of the screen.

```
<style>
    span[tooltip]:hover:after{
        content: attr(tooltip);
        margin-left:auto;
        }
</style>
<p><span tooltip='url("graphics/new_folder")'>Click "New">"Folder upload"</span> and upload the folder from its location</p>
```

Simply renders the text `url("graphics/new_folder")` after the `span` element. Replacing `content: attr(tooltip);` with `content:url("graphics/new_folder")` displays the image, but styling interacts with it weirdly. Giving it `position:fixed`, `float:right`, and `float:top` not only don't change its position, but also don't effect the image from the perspective of the viewport. Giving it `height` and `width` values plays with the positioning weirdly, too.

So, multiple questions here:

1. How can I make `content:attr(tooltip)` effectively render an image?
2. How can I make properties properly apply to the image/get the image to the top right of the screen?
3. Have I been oblivious to an API that could do this? I would expect one to exist, but can't find one.

I've been grappling with this for a while now, help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set the image tag as `<img src='my_image' style='display:none;' id='open'>`

Now with the tag element that requires the hovering should have an `onMouseover` event with the call of `document.getElementById('open').style.display=` taught that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this by css `content:attr()` you have to use `<img src="">` inside span and than hover on it image will show but you can't do this by css `content:attr()` .

Alternative u can do the same thing by using `data` Attr i.e `data-tooltip="graphics/new_folder"`

Comment: Could you clarify? What css would I use to be able to use the value `data-*`? The MDN user guide on `data-*` says to use attr().